# Why the functions possess the same infinite asymptotic expansion as $t\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Hi guys I am trying to prove to myself that $\frac{1+e^{-t}}{1+t}$ and $\frac{1}{1+t}$ have the same asymptotic expansion as $t\rightarrow \infty$

Please correct me if I am wrong, but my thinking is to derive an expantion for each one of them let us call the expantions $e_1(t)$ and $e_2(t)$ then observe that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e_2(t)}{e_1(t)}= 1$. My question is this enough? And do my calculations look okay.

$\frac{1}{1+t}= \frac{1}{t}- \frac{1}{t^2}+ \frac{1}{t^3} -O(\frac{1}{t^4})$

Where we can call this $e_1(t)$. We do similarity for the other one

$\frac{1+e^{-t}}{1+t}=(1+e^{-t})\frac{1}{1+t} =(e^{-t}+1)\left[\frac{1}{t}- \frac{1}{t^2}+ \frac{1}{t^3} -O(\frac{1}{t^4})\right]$

which we can call $e_2$ then if we look at the

$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e_2(t)}{e_1(t)}= 1$.

What do you guys think is this an exceptionable explanation?

Comment: It looks correct to me, though I'd wait for confirmation from someone with more experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is this enough?

No. To have "the same asymptotic expansion" is... to have the same asymptotic expansion. That is, the two asympotic expansions (mind you, in some prescribed sequence of functions - I guess it's $\{t^{-1},t^{-2}\cdots\}$ here) must be identical. That the ratio tends to one only shows that the functions have the same order of growth, which is a much weaker property.

BTW, in you resolution, $e_2$ is *not* an asymptotic expansion.

Actually, you already know the candidate a.e. of the second function... You need to prove that

$$ e(t)= \frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t^2}+\frac{1}{t^3}-\cdots$$

is indeed an a.e. of $$f_2(t)=\frac{1+e^{-t}}{1+t}$$

For this, [you must show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) that

$$\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t^2}+\cdots + (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{t^n} - f_2(t) = o( \frac{1}{t^n})$$

Comment: Sorry to ask but how would you expand then for $e_2(t)$?

Comment: Let me see if I understand.So $f_2(t)= \frac{1}{1+t}+ \frac{e^t}{1+t}$. Thus we can say that the first par of  the sum will cancel with the $\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{t^2}+\dots (-1)^{n+1} \frac{1}{t^n}$.  Then the only the tale of the series survives So we have $O(\frac{1}{t})+\frac{e^t}{1+t}$